# Looping through objects in an array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm putting together this script which pulls two child elements from a containing div #mini_ads, adds them to an array. I want to be able to use the array to select them via index in order to manip. them individually.

I know I can just select them w/o even using an array of course, but I want this array as I may add multiple more elements later.

The issue is that I am not able to select the items individually by their index in the array. The current script I've got going is selecting and manipulating both objects in the array as if they're both index[0].

```
var miniAds = $('#mini_ads');
var elements = miniAds.children();
var changeWtime;
var adsArr = new Array();
var i = 0;
var x = 0;
adsArr.push(elements);
console.log(adsArr);
adsArr[i].css("display", "none");   
var changeWtime = setInterval(function () {
    for (x; x < 1; x++) {
        return x;
        while (x > i) {
            adsArr[1].css("display", "block");
        }
    };
}, 5000);
console.log(x);
changeWtime;
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong here. Assistance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your array only has one entry, which is a jQuery object with the DOM elements. I.e. `adsArr[0]` indeed refers to both elements (the jQuery object). In your code `elements` is a jQuery object and `adsArr.push(elements)` adds that object to the array.

Comment: That `while` loop will never be reached

Comment: For your question. the main issue is that you insert an array to array.
adsArr.push(elements);
elements is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues with your code

- You're creating a double array when you push `elements` into 'adsArr':

  ```
  adsArr.push(elements);
  ```
- You're throwing a return statement in the for loop:

  ```
  for (x; x < 1; x++ ){
      return x;
      // ...
  ```
- You have a double loop for no reason `while` inside of the `for`.

### Solution

I was going to explain the solution to this verbally, but after coding an example I realized that there is too much to explain this is another solution similar to yours:

```
var miniAds = $('#mini_ads'),
    elements = miniAds.children(),
    i = 2,
    x = 0;

elements.hide();

var changeWtime = setInterval(function () {
  if ( x < i ) {
      $(elements[x]).show();
  }

  x++;
}, 5000);
```

### [Link to example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UKOJiB/2/edit).

Comment: This is quite helpful as well as simplifies things, however, something is still not quite there. It seems the elements are not being captured.

Comment: Correction: it pulls the elements fine into an array(elements). However, the selector within the if statement is not triggering to show.

Comment: Nvm, forgot to call the interval function

Comment: Hmm... it seems there is an issue still due to using a legacy version of jQuery. This works on current jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: @KALD You shouldn't have any issues with legacy jQuery. `$(element)` and `.children()` are supported since `jQuery v1.0`.

Comment: Yes, there seemed to be something wrong with 1.7.1 min.js, probably something conflicting in that version. Either way I updated the copy to 1.7.2 and it works fine. The only thing is getting it to loop properly now.

Comment: @KALD What's the issue with the loop?

Comment: hitauto, I've adjusted the script a bit to get the loop that I want. Thanks!

Comment: var miniAds = $('#mini_ads'),
    elements = miniAds.children(),
    i = elements.length,
    x = 0;

var changeWtime = setInterval(function () {
elements.hide();
  if (x > i) { x= 0;}
 if ( x < i ) {
      $(elements[x]).show();
 }
 x++;
}, 3000);

Comment: hitauto, actually the issue with this was indeed NOT the jQuery version. It was a selector issue. For some reason the jQuery method was not working within the if statement to .show(). I used the standard JS css change as someone mentioned below. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi u should push child divs as below function does and after that i believe u can perform ur task...

```
var adsArr= [];

$('#mini_ads').children().each(
    function(i){
        adsArr.push(this);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript use .styles()

.css() which is a JQuery method but not Javascript

ref http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer :)